# How to get callback value Outside the function

Tags: android, android-volley

I am using volley library and have made a callback but after getting the result in callback. How should I assign it to another variable and use in same activity.

```
IResult getResult = new IResult() 

 {      @Override
            public void notifySuccess(String requestType, String response) {

            }

            @Override
            public void notifyError(String requestType, VolleyError error) {

            }
        };
```

Comment: Declare variable globally and directly assign in notifySuccess. OR write function and send response as parameter to that function and assign variables in function.

Comment: I have done same thing but when I check Logcat . I don't get the response in variable.

Comment: Update your question with code which you are using to display as well as plz add json response coming from Response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define variable in your activity and assign it from callback.
if you want to update view from this result you can call method from result callback.

```
 String apiResult=null;  

    IResult getResult = new IResult() 

     {      @Override
                public void notifySuccess(String requestType, String response) {
                  apiResult=response
                  //or call method for update UI
                }

                @Override
                public void notifyError(String requestType, VolleyError error) {
                  //or call method for update UI
                }
            };
```

Hope this will help you.